# BSOD Asus G750JM Win8.1

Tags: windows, windows-8, drivers, windows-8.1, bsod

I have been getting random reboots and/or bsod's on my G750JM that I very recently bought. Everytime it does this the error is:

**DRIVER_POWER_STATE_FAILURE**

The bug check in my event logs shows this:

```
- System 

  - Provider 

   [ Name]  Microsoft-Windows-WER-SystemErrorReporting 
   [ Guid]  {ABCE23E7-DE45-4366-8631-84FA6C525952} 
   [ EventSourceName]  BugCheck 

  - EventID 1001 

   [ Qualifiers]  16384 

   Version 0 

   Level 2 

   Task 0 

   Opcode 0 

   Keywords 0x80000000000000 

  - TimeCreated 

   [ SystemTime]  2014-06-12T05:34:20.000000000Z 

   EventRecordID 4824 

   Correlation 

  - Execution 

   [ ProcessID]  0 
   [ ThreadID]  0 

   Channel System 

   Computer beardedeagle 

   Security 


- EventData 

  param1 0x0000009f (0x0000000000000003, 0xffffe00070fa7880, 0xffffd000209f0930, 0xffffe00070ff49c0) 
  param2 C:\Windows\MEMORY.DMP 
  param3 061214-29187-01
```

I checked the MEMORY.DMP and as far as I can see it is empty (unless I am not opening it with a specific program, totally possible since windows is not my normal thing.)

I have tried several things to try to pinpoint the problem such as reseating the ram and the hard drives, "Error Checking" the disk under disk properties, running a memory check, verifying all the drivers installed have signitures, updating to the latest NVIDIA driver, updating to the latest INF driver, and making sure I am running the most recent bios version.  I have also run a system file check and uninstalled all asus bloatware that is in the install/uninstall manager.  I cannot seem to get a handle on the situation or find anything truly helpful through Google searches.

Here is the minidump:

https://files.secureserver.net/0su9ZHsQyRtfE5

I have also enabled verifier.exe to run against all drivers and will keep it running for somet time. Any and all help/suggestions are much appreciated. If more information is needed I can provide it.

I am not sure what all information is needed from bluescreenview but here is a screenshot:

[image]

*Update: After removing the bloatware and enabling the verifier.exe application it has been about 24 hours since the last reboot or bsod. Will updated if it happens again. Any additional information is appreciated as I would like to get to the bottom of this.

Comment: share the smaller dmp files from C:\Windows\minidump (upload them as a zip to a cloud service and post a link)

Comment: added the minidump

Comment: Use BlueScreenViewer so we don't have to download the dump, read the information, for you.  I already know its going to be the driver that handles your battery management and/or chipset.

Comment: it talks about ntoskrnl.exe but I will get that info in the question.

Comment: also don't know if this relates to anything you are refering to when you say battery management, but this occurs when it is on battery power or AC power.

Comment: the crash comes from a device with ID VEN_8086&DEV_0C01. Run PCI-Z to see which Intel device this is. http://www.pci-z.com/

Comment: Xeon E3-1200 v3/4th Gen Core Processor PCI Express x16 Controller

Comment: As far as I can see online, I am running the most current version of that driver.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Removing the bloatware and enabling the verifier is what fixed it for me. Closing question.